# What does "less a matter of action than of appearance" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Though reassuring, the assumption that powerful leaders make a difference is often misleading. Cohen and March compare the command and control of college presidents to that of the driver of a skidding automobile:“The marginal judgments he makes, his skill, and his luck will probably make some difference to the life prospects of his riders. As a result, his responsibilities are heavy. But whether he is convicted of manslaughter or receives a medal for heroism is largely outside his control”(1974, p. 203).
>
> As with other processes, a leader’s power is **less a matter of action than of appearance**.

What does the phrase "less a matter of action than of appearance" mean in this context?

Source: [Google Books](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=xUgbAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT437)

Comment: If you want to keep posting links to Google books, please 1) explain your research in your question, and 2) please stop posting the full URL.  I've edited your questions many times to show you how to do this.  I'll do so one last time, but in the future please make more of an effort.  Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know why the full URL appears here. On other forums, like this one: https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/though-reassuring.3574240/#post-18179535, it doesn't.

Comment: haile - Click [HERE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/editing-help#links) for more information on how to format a link on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

> "it is less  a matter of action (what they do)  than of appearence (what they look like they are doing)."

What leaders look like, and what they seem to be doing is more important than what they actually do.

Answer (score 0):

> Less a matter of [one thing] than of [another thing].

Lets first look at the word matter in the context of the above phrase it means:

> **Matter** - a subject or situation under consideration.[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matter)

The the first part of the sentence can be considered to mean:

> Is is less (to a smaller degree - [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/less)) a subject of what they do...

Now the second half of the sentence is just shorter way of saying:

> ... but instead a matter of ...

this is because the word **than** introduces a second element in a comparison.

To summarise the author is saying that this is **appearance** is what is more important to a leaders power, rather than action.